# How do I save only duplicate lines from a huge file based on a substring from a column?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a huge file (around 100Gb) on a Linux machine, which contains duplicate substrings inside second column.
Example:

> 92957ea93f634985;02a2**a09322bbbb2d894c**;acfb4aa85f577db320d5a0701210238f
> 62be40ee38d3d62e;1f433**e74c9498f051bca**;4ad1905e8ff598e9ea5b71c0e48424d9
> 08356a4e6e5edc25;5d41**a09322bbbb2d894c**;d92ef5610121033f34dd881b4b910820
> c5a2cd0c4e2191e3;83fd*c9498f051bcab9e8*;5bcb136cfd3326br9d1f52ce7537b901
> 1e3a1f877316966d;12ff**3e74c9498f051bca**;a9547b3db00e821bf5e8db900121038e
> 00c5a857928fbfaf;547b*3db00e821b1604eh*;11919d5616e4306x4a495118f52c41d4
> 92ea3e74c9498f04;8fac**a09322bbbb2d894c**;10256a9ff1787f483db00e862119030a

I expect the following output:

> 92957ea93f634985;02a2**a09322bbbb2d894c**;acfb4aa85f577db320d5a0701210238f
> 62be40ee38d3d62e;1f43**3e74c9498f051bca**;4ad1905e8ff598e9ea5b71c0e48424d9
> 08356a4e6e5edc25;5d41**a09322bbbb2d894c**;d92ef5610121033f34dd881b4b910820
> 1e3a1f877316966d;12ff**3e74c9498f051bca**;a9547b3db00e821bf5e8db900121038e
> 92ea3e74c9498f04;8fac**a09322bbbb2d894c**;10256a9ff1787f483db00e862119030a

(line order is not important)

I tried on a smaller test file with the following code:

```
awk -F";" '!_[substr($2,5,16)]++' test.csv
```

but it shows only the first occurrence and I need to save all of them.
Because it's a huge file I cannot use a solution which implies loading into memory, so I don't think the code above is good.
I need to save only the lines which contain the same values of the substring inside column 2 defined above, so any help would be appreciated.

edit: made a mistake. the code above doesn't work. it shows the first duplicate because I mistyped the delimiter. with the correct one it shows the whole content of the file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a representative example (a few lines covering as many different cases as possible) and the output you would expect from that example. Also explain, in words, what you want to happen. The code you show will only print unique entries, but that doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: I can't determine what you need. Maybe use some colors?

Comment: I used bold for duplicate values and italic for unique ones

Comment: Thank you for sharing your work. For your next posts, please create a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. There is much noise in this data and it is difficult to sort out what you want (although the bold did help!).

Comment: Well, for me easiest way would be to use python. 
https://www.journaldev.com/32059/read-large-text-files-in-python
You can then use construct if substring in string do something.

Comment: I doubt you could easily solve this task in AWK, Python, etc., unless you have a very large main memory (~ the size of the data) or very much time. It is also important where the substings are exactly located and how log they are. Normally one would use some kind of big data framework to solve this task.

Comment: Given you had enough main memory I would use the following algorithm. Two scans of the file. In the first scan create a map with substrings as keys and count the occurences as values. Then iterate through the map and remove all keys with count one. In the second scan print all lines that have a substring that is a key in the resulting map.

Comment: The awk command you present is printing unique lines, to print only duplicates you have to request `seen[$substr()] > 1`, after having parsed the whole file once and counted the occurences of the hashed substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### awk

If the substring to test is around 20% of each line and your file is 100GB, then the typical `awk` solution could need up to 20GB of memory. This solution requires a 2-pass parsing of the file (or storing all lines in memory which would be even worse), first store the substrings in an associative array while counting their occurences, and then print anything that was not unique.

```bsh
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[substr($0,22,16)]++; next} seen[substr($0,22,16)] > 1' file file
```

But in your case, this associative array may not fit into memory.

---

### sort

For a solution that will handle memory, you can use `sort`. It will use available memory only, if necessary it will use temporary files and merge-sort them. It could be slower but it can do it even on a low memory box.

```bsh
LC_ALL=C sort -k1.22,1.37 file | uniq -D -s21 -w16
```

You may remove the `LC_ALL=C` if your file contains non UTF-8 multi-byte characters and you may also need to define a different tmp location for the `sort` command, with `-T, --temporary-directory=DIR` pointing somewhere with 100GB available and the required permissions, in case your `/tmp` does not have 100 GB free (sometimes `/` partitions are small)

The above `uniq` will skip the first 21 characters and test uniqueness for the first 16 after them. `-D` will print only the duplicated lines. Similar to this, the above `sort` command is testing the same fixed characters range for every line.

---

### extract only duplicated substrings & awk

Depending on your data, you could try this solution, combining ideas from above and trying to fit into memory and be faster, actually this is the `awk` solution fitting into memory. This command:

```bsh
cut -c22-37 file | sort | uniq -d > subs.txt
```

will extract the substrings appearing twice or more in the specified fixed position in your file. It will print each of them only once into `subs.txt`. Note that the size of `subs.txt` will be smaller than the size of the associative array in the first solution because uniques have been excluded.

Now, if the size of `subs.txt` is small enough and fits into memory (it depends on the duplication frequency), you can parse the file only once:

```bsh
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$0]; next} (substr($0,22,16) in seen)' subs.txt file >> output
```

Or you can split this file to N pieces, using `split -l` and run the above command parsing N times the file, each time appending to the same output file. Depending on the size of `subs.txt`, if this could be done in 1-2 steps, I think it would be faster than the total sort solution.

Comment: I think I will use some kind of sql (cassandra or mongodb) to achieve what I need. But I really appreciate your time and effort for trying to help me, so I accept your solution. Thanks!

Comment: What is the size of all your duplicated substrings? (unique values of them). Did you try to create that file (`subs.txt` in my last solution) ? I guess it is less than your physical memory.

Comment: BTW usually people call dbs like mongo as "no-sql", or document databases, if you want a pure sql solution, you can use a standard sql database also. If this is one-off task, wth no other relationships, just testing for duplicated substrings in fixed positions, on a standalone box, you will give more time and more resources using a document db.